# JavaScript runtime error: '$' is undefined - using MVC 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

In my _Layout.cshtml I have the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Intranet Ads</title>
        <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function search() {
                var searchVal = $('#txtSearchString').val();
                $('#adResults #summary').each(function () {
                    if (searchVal == '') {
                        $(this).parent().show();
                    } else {
                        $(this).not(':contains(' + searchVal + ')').parent().hide();
                    }
                });
            }

        function openEditAd(val) {
            if (val != 'admin') {
                $("#edit-content,#edit-background").toggleClass("active");
                $("#txtConfirmationEdit").text = "";
            } else {
                $("#edit-content-admin,#edit-background-admin").toggleClass("active");
                $("#txtConfirmationEdit").text = "";
            }
        }

        function closeEditAd(permission) {
            if (permission != 'admin') {
                if ($("#txtConfirmationEdit").val().trim() != "") {
                    var url = '@Url.Action("Edit", new { id = "__id__" })';
                    window.location.href = url.replace('__id__', $("#txtConfirmationEdit").val());
                }

                $("#edit-content,#edit-background").toggleClass("active");
            } else {
                if ($("#txtConfirmationAdmin").val().trim() != "") {
                    var url = '@Url.Action("Edit", new { id = "__id__" })';
                    window.location.href = url.replace('__id__', $("#txtConfirmationAdmin").val());
                }

                $("#edit-content-admin,#edit-background-admin").toggleClass("active");
            }
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            // Handler for .ready() called.
            console.log("hi");
        });


    </script>
</head>
<body>
...
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
```

I just added the:

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            // Handler for .ready() called.
            console.log("hi");
        });
```

To the end as I'm trying to implement a datepicker but I'm getting the

> JavaScript runtime error: '$' is undefined

As you can see in my other functions I am using jQuery commands...  What is the reason for this?

I was getting the exact same error when I had this in as well:

```
$(document).ready(
    function () {
        $('.datepicker').datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            minDate: "-99Y",
            dateFormat: "dd/mm/yyyy"
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to put the JQuery reference first, at the top of the page.  Browsers load script tags synchronously, so if you try to reference JQuery's `$` before loading the JQuery source, then you'll get an "undefined" error.

Actually, since script tags block the rest of the page from loading, it might be better to instead put your other script tags at the bottom, underneath the JQuery reference.  This allows the browser to load and display your page markup first, before loading the scripts.  (This can give the impression of a faster page load.)

Comment: How can I tell?  I'm using the ASP MVC 4 template.  I don't see a script tag like in normal web pages.

Comment: Well, then place your script after  `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")` in the body

Comment: hmmm...  That didn't work.  I got the same error.  In the output window I'm seeing the following: 0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: SyntaxError
Exception was thrown at line 5303, column 7 in http://localhost:6281/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js

Comment: @webdad3 The JQuery script is throwing the error? That's pretty strange. What's happening at line 5303?

Comment: @McGarnagle - You were right.  I just wasn't seeing what you were talking about until today!  Thanks for your help

Comment: What do you mean put the JQuery reference first? I have a question open (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21311225/how-to-use-jquery-in-header-master-page) and I put the reference in the `HEAD` section but I am still seeing the error.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue. Open Views\Shared_Layout.cshtml and move the following script registration's sentences from the bottom of the body section, to the head section:

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")

Comment: This fixes my problem, but why does the default Visual Studio _Layout.cshtml file have it at the bottom of the body section?  Won't it be an issue for everyone?

Answer (score 0):

try referencing them directly ie:

```
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```