# How to use JQuery in header.master page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have a header.master `ASP` page and I am trying to handle a button click.

My `MasterPage.master` has the following codes:

```
<%@ Master Language="VB" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.vb" Inherits="MasterPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

In `Default.aspx` page I have the following code:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"/>
<asp:Button ID="Button2" text="Search" runat="server"/>
    </div>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                //write your code here
                var txt = $('input[id$=TextBox2]').val();
                $("input[id$=Button2]").click(function () {
                    alert("Hello world!");
                });
            });
</script>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Everytime I click the button I get the following error: `0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: '$' is undefined`

My HTML source code has this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>

</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="Default.aspx" id="form1">
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="7dUu7W1yzgwgCERTGi4lbDb7UGbWC6oigS9K1dTKxNLxOKUQzVp9hkyhbKT/e5Ve22nU2D7eaALUFm2bnAuOroUPGHMRph/IDyBFloPmn0I=" />
</div>

<div class="aspNetHidden">

    <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="QCYR7lPBzDC4MzimaH8vIZhF02sSXZE7Cf62VB3M7wEBPRqcglslWJOpXkEEhd9Uw5st2qukgt5t0k0g4Wht3U04fUZzVjfVER5iHbnrs9HEnjwqYebT1BCrLysKW9hhIPI4IIcy1JzrwgDvl0Yvpw==" />
</div>
    <div>
    <input name="TextBox1" type="text" id="TextBox1" />
<input type="submit" name="Button2" value="Search" id="Button2" />
    </div>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                //write your code here
                var txt = $('input[id$=TextBox2]').val();
                $("input[id$=Button2]").click(function () {
                    alert("Hello world!");
                });
            });
</script>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you post the HTML generated by this asp tags?

Comment: I added the source and it looks fine to me but for some reason it's not handling the onclick method.

Comment: I've pasted your code in JSFiddle and it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/5ytU4/

Comment: What you think could be wrong on my end? Because everytime I press the button it just refreshes the page. Any way to figure that out?

Comment: Try to put return false; after  alert("1");

Comment: I created a brand new site and created two pages. One is `Default.aspx` and the other is `MasterPage.master` I put the JQuery code and the URL link in the `Default.aspx` page. When I try to view the page, `I get a 0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: '$' is undefined` error. Any idea?

Comment: @SiKni8 you get that error when you don't have a reference to jQuery, or you are using `$` before your reference. You can't do `$(document).ready...` before the script reference the jQuery CDN.

Comment: I did it after the script reference.

Comment: @SiKni8 I doubt that, considering your code examples don't match up. You show `ClientIDMode="Static"` on your button and yet your rendered HTML is `id="ctl00_Button2"` (i.e. *not* static.)... and then there is `script` code after your button even though you say you put it in the head.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to update my question. It's updated now :)

Comment: @SiKni8 your HTML source still does not match. Also `$` could be undefined if you are on `https` since your jQuery reference is `http` and could be getting blocked by browser. Otherwise, the code you posted should work, as I copied it verbatim, and it works. (the `asp` code, not the rendered html code)

Comment: Let me modify my codes and will post an update. I deleted the HTML source from my question for less confusion. For some reason in my ASP pages using JavaScript, `location.href="www.google.com";` just reloads my page without redirecting. Any idea why?

Comment: I update my question to show everything and What would you recommend for me to fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can not use the asp.net control id using `#` in javascript.

so try this code to use asp.net control id in javascript as below.

```
    $("#<%=Button2.ClientID %>").click(function() 
    {
        alert("Hello World.");
    });
```

i hope it will help you.

Comment: I get the following error: `The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).`

Comment: Yes, he can use the control ID, as he has `ClientIDMode="Static"`.

Comment: I update my question to show everything and What would you recommend for me to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: When I was running it directly from MVS, I keep getting the error. When I loaded it by itself, it's working! Silly me.